# Get iCloud storage plan and quota via Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, icloud, command-line, storage

I am aware that the command:

```
brctl quota
```

Will (as long as it's run from a logged-in session) display the number of bytes remaining in the user's iCloud storage.

I am looking for a way to programmatically determine the allocated storage (aka the "plan") eg 5GB, 50GB, 200GB.

Is this possible?

Comment: Which macOS version is that command found in? My Monterey doesn't have it. In fact the only `brctl` I'm aware of is for Linux network bridge admin.

Comment: @AndyGriffiths Weird... On my Intel-based Mac running Monterey 12.6, the command is here: `/usr/bin/brctl`. It even has a man page. Interestingly, `quote` is not listed as an option.

Comment: Aha! You are completely correct and it's my error! Silly me was checking for the command while ssh'd to another machine, a Linux box which does not have the bridged networking components installed. Between the checks I'd been logged out and hadn't even noticed the different command prompt. I suppose I should change my env vars to make my prompt dayglo....

Comment: `quota` doesn't appear in the manpage, but does show up in the default help if you just type `brctl`. However it doesn't leave you any the wiser....

Comment: @jaume The command is `quota` — not "quote"